# How do I pass parameter TO SSRS report FROM ASP.NET page which has the reportviewer for the report

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2008

I have an ASP.NET page which has report viewer control to access reports from report manager.

- I need to pass report parameter from this ASP.NET page to the report server.
- I want to pass region number based on user logged in, which is displayed on a label in ASP.NET page.

Thanks.

Comment: It´s a bit late but I have teh same problem and resolved using this video tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psLVbNx0GtU And using the solution posted by Mcbeev.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming your using remote processing of the report.

Then do the following:

```
ReportParameter p = new ReportParameter("ParamName", "ParamVal");
reportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p });
```

**From**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252178(VS.80).aspx

**Good example**: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/reporting-services/ReportViewer2005.aspx